# c# See what process is changing filename of specific file

Tags: c#, file

Is there a way in c# to find out what process is changing a name of a file when it's changed. I know how to see if the name is changed, but is there a way to see exactly what program/process that is doing it?

Answer (score 0):

By enabling *SACL* in active directory or locally on the computer, you can audit who changed a file on a computer.  Then you can configure a C# application to monitor the eventvwr.msc for any file changes.  Follow these instructions to setup auditing: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/814595.

Another suggestion is to use this existing C# application to find out who has a lock on the file: https://gist.github.com/i-e-b/2290426.

I believe monitoring the eventvwr.msc will be a better approach, because it gives you the flexibility to monitor a range of modifications (read,write,delete,update,changes,locks).

Comment: You can configure a C# application to monitor the objects within the event viewer easily.  I'm just referencing Event Viewer as eventvwr.msc.  But as you wish - The best approach is to configure the C# application to monitor the application, security, and/or system log files within the Event Viewer....

Comment: Oh I wasn't aware MMC had an automation model.  +1 :)

Comment: Take care with the code linked from GitHub! It leaks (unamaged) memory and other unmanaged resources.

Comment: Further notice... if you shall use the linked code, don't forget to close handles created by Duplicatehandle(). DuplicateHandle() increases the reference count for mutexes and semaphores therefore could lock objects if CloseHandle() isn't called to close the duplicated handles.